# Observe an array of RxJS observables one by one and get notified when all of them are done

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have a file upload service in angular 2 that returns a observable for the fileUpload method. Assume I have more than 1 file uploading. I want to be able to show status of each file of it being uploaded or not, and also to do some other actions when all of them finish.

So it is something like this.

```
uploadAll(files): void {
   let fileUploadObservables = [];

   files.forEach(file => {
      fileUploadObservables
      .push(this.fileUploadService.upload(file));
   });


    Observable.forkJoin(...fileUploadObservables)
            .subscribe((res) => {
               //Do something else when all files finish uploading
            });
}
```

forkJoin only notifies me when all of them has finished loading, but I need to be notified when each of them finishes, and when all of them finish. I can only do one of them with the observables.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check when all observables have completed, you should pass a third parameter to the `subscribe` method. The `subscribe` method takes up to 3 parameters. Consider:

```
someObservableOfObservable().subscribe(
  (observableResult) => {
    // I will execute each time a value pass through this stream
  },
  (error) => {
    // I will execute if any exception/error is thrown
  },
  () => {
    // I will execute when the Observable stream is exhausted
  }
)
```